# Is it possible for ransack to find all the related association items while searching with them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Assume `post` has many `categories` and it has an N:N relationship and I want to search for all the `posts` that have a certain `category` AND all the `categories` for the resulting `posts`.

For example, if `posts` and `categories` are like these,

| post | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 |
| 2 | 2,3,4 |
| 3 | 1,3 |

and when I search for `category`=1, I want:

| post | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 |
| 3 | 1,3 |

As there are many search parameters given with a form, so I want to use ransack, and here is the code I tried:

```
Post.ransack(params[:q]).result.includes(:categories)
```

And I got this:

| post | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

I know it is possible with a pure Rails query using `left_join`:

```
Post.left_joins(:categories).where('categories.id':1).first.categories
```

However, `left_join`ing anywhere in the ransack query did not work.

Is it possible to do this with ransack?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code is work for you.
Open the rails console and write like below. I'am assuming your Category model contains NAME column.

```
Post.ransack(category_id_eq: "1").result
```

OR

```
Post.ransack(category_id_matches: "1").result
```

OR Multiple queries on ids

```
Post.ransack(category_id_matches_any: "1,2,3,4,5,6").result
```

Comment: I don't have a model named `Tag` and it does not necessarily have a `name` column. I want to search for `category`'s ID.

Comment: I updated post. You can try again.

Comment: Does it work when I want to search for multiple `category` IDs?

Comment: For this try, Post.ransack(category_id_matches_any: "1").result

Comment: It works, however, I'd like to note that when I want to list all the `categories` for matching `post`s to make the table in the question, it causes N+1 queries. It was solved by adding `.include(:categories)` after the `.result`.